# NHibernate : update an ISet collection

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

See the class and mapping below. I'd like in some case update the address (at this time, it's all the time one address).

I do this :

```
var customer = session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
customer.Address.Clear();
customer.Address.Add(address);
```

address is coming from a form, the id field is not = 0 (when 0, at creation, no problem)

but when I do this :

```
session.Save(customer);
session.Commit();
```

I receive an exception on the commit (14 is the id of CustomerAddress) :

*a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 14, of entity: CustomerAddress*

What is the way to update this address  ?

Thanks,

**Class and Mapping**

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<CustomerAddress> Address { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        Address = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<CustomerAddress>(); 
    }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.LastName)
            .Length(50)
            .Not.Nullable();    
        HasMany(x => x.Address)
            .AsSet()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class CustomerAddressMap : ClassMap<CustomerAddress>
{
    public CustomerAddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Street).Length(50);
        References(x => x.Customer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the address you are saving already has an id assigned to it you can simply do the following:

```
var customer = session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
Session.Merge(address);  // This will copy your transient entity into 
                         // ..an entity with the same id that is in the 
                         // ..first level cache.
session.SaveOrUpdate(customer);
```

You are getting that error  because and address with an ID of 14 is already associated with your NHibernate session.  So when you create the new detached transient entity and try to save it with that id NHibernate throws an error.  Generally this is a good thing as it is very rare to want to do what you are doing.

A far better pattern would be to have a ViewModel for the fields of an address that are changeable by a user, and then do the following:

```
var address = Session.Get<Address>(addressVM.Id);
Mapper.Map(addressVM, address); // This is some type of mapper to copy properties 
                                // ..from one object to another.  I like automapper               
                                // ..for this
Session.SaveOrUpdate(address);
```

Comment: I tried the second solution. It's strange there no update but an insert. The `address` variable has the id = 14 and I have an insert (and not an update and then 2 addresse)

Comment: @Kris-l  Thanks for pointing out an error in my code Session.Save() should have been Session.SaveOrUpdate().  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *updating* an address, why are you clearing the collection and re-adding?

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var customer = session.Get<Customer>(customerId);
    var address = customer.Address.Single(/*optional condition here*/);
    //or, if you are not updating the Customer, this might be better
    var address = session.Get<Address>(addressId);
    address.Street = updatedStreetInfo;
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I find this method cumbersome when I am editing an address usually `ALL` the fields apart from the `Id` **could** be updated. I suppose its what we have to play with...

Comment: @Rippo Why? You always have to assign the values, either to a new instance, or an existing one. The patterns for change-tracking are well-defined and apply to any ORM, not just NH.

Comment: I agree with you 100% I just find it cumbersome thats all